# Lost in MVVM, Trying to connect M to VM to V

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

So here is what i  am trying to do. I want to pass the string techName from the model to the view... and I am not understanding how to do this. I can do it from the ViewModel to the view just fine but I want the data to sit in the Model and get pulled by the ViewModel and pass to the View. so that the data can be used across multiple views. That being said here is what I have

MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DefaultViewClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       DataContext = new DefaultViewModel();
    }

    private void NewCallClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = new NewCallViewModel();
    }
}
```

View:

```
Text="{Binding model.TechName}
```

ViewModel:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;
using callFlow.Models;


namespace callFlow.ViewModels
{
    public class DefaultViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<DataModel> model = new ObservableCollection<DataModel>();

        public DefaultViewModel() { }

        private DataModel _selectedModel;
        public DataModel SelectedModel
        {
            get { return _selectedModel ?? (_selectedModel = new SelectedModel()); }
            set { _selectedModel = value; }
        }

        public void changeSelectedModel(DataModel newSelectedModel)
        {
            SelectedModel.TechName = newSelectedModel.TechName;
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace callFlow.Models
{
    public class DataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string techName ="this is a test";

        public DataModel()
        {

        }

        public string TechName
        {
            get { return techName; }
            set { techName = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string techName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(techName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? What is not working as you expected it to work?

Answer (score 3):

Your Datacontext class `DefaultViewModel` does not have any `model` property.

So you have to replace your XAML with this:

```
Text="{Binding SelectedModel.TechName}
```